# How to use rxjs/Observables inside Nestjs Application w/o Controller

Tags: axios, rxjs, nestjs

Nestjs [suggests](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/http-module) to use the `HttpModule`, imported from `@nestjs/axios` to perform requests to external APIs.
I understand that the `HttpService` transforms the responses into `Observables`.

### Goal

Request data from an external API and use the data inside the application.

### Problem

I fail to understand how to actually retrieve the data from the request. I read in some other answers, that if you return the observable from a `Controller`, Nestjs will automatically handle it for you and return the data to the client. That's great, however, I am not using it inside a `Controller`. I need the data to be available inside the application.

I have a service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

  // constructor

  getData(): Observable<AxiosResponse<any[]>> {
    return this.httpService.get(`http://some-url.com`);
  }

}
```

How would use `getData()` within the application logic to get to the data returned by the `Observable` ? And would it be better, in that case, to use a plain axios request with `Promises` and not use the `HttpModule` ?

The only solution I found so far is using `subscribe` :

```js
this.httpService.get(`http://some-url.com`)
.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Which seems to be would end up in a callback hell, compared to all the fancy `async ... awaits`.

Comment: you can call `getData` and subscribe to it . `this.service.getData().subscribe`

Comment: This would be the same as calling `httpService.get().subscribe`  which I already included in my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### The Answer

> The only solution I found so far is using subscribe

Bingo. That's how it's done :)

#### Some Elaboration

> Which seems to be would end up in a callback hell, compared to all the fancy async ... awaits

Not really. As a library built to be declarative, RxJS makes it easy to structure your callbacks.

async/await is just syntactic sugar for `promise`s and `.then`. It's a language feature, but even without async/await promises bind to one another nicely and avoid deep nesting and 'callback hell'

So while observables don't (and probably never will) enjoy fist-class language constructs like `async/await`, that doesn't mean they won't manage some (or a lot) of complexity for you.

---

The RxJS library is built so that, generally, you should never have to nest subscriptions.

The following is considered an anti-pattern:

```ts
stream1().subscribe(value1 => 
  stream2(value1).subscribe(value2 => {
    /* Do something with value2 */
  })
)
```

It would more idiomatically be written as:

```ts
stream1().pipe(
  mergeMap(value1 => stream2(value1))
).subscribe(value2 => {
  /* Do something with value2 */
})
```

Notice how a level of indentation is removed and you only need to subscribe once?

Observables come with a set of higher-order operators that act as highly customizable `.then`s for streams of values instead of just individual values.

#### Another Way: Convert to Promises

Observables are a superset of promises, which means you can turn any promise into an observable but you lose structure if you want to convert an observable into a promise. Often this isn't an issue, but let me explain by analogy.

If promises are a container for a value, then observables are a container for a list of values.

I can take any value and create a list out of it. I'll just have a list of length 1.

```ts
a_value = 5
// convert with:
list_values = [a_value]
```

I can't take any list and create a value out of it. I can take the first value, or the last value (If there's only one, those might be the same), if the list is empty, maybe I need to throw an error? Maybe there's a default value I'd be happy with?

Maybe I have a way to reduce multiple values into a single value. Perhaps I can turn a list of integers into a value by adding them all together.

```ts
list_values = [1,2,3,4,5]
// convert with:
value = list_values[0] || 0
// or
value = list_values[list_values.length - 1] || 100
// or
value = sum(list_values)
```

Back to promises. RxJS has `firstValueFrom` and `lastValueFrom` as utility functions that wrap a promise around an observable.

```ts
firstValueFrom(
  this.httpService.get(`http://some-url.com`)
).then(value => {
  /* Do something with value */
});

// or with await as syntactic sugar

value = await lastValueFrom(
  this.httpService.get(`http://some-url.com`)
);
/* Do something with value */
```

These are typically enough for something like an http request (since those only return a single value). More complex approaches tend me be handled on the RxJS side before being converted into a promise.

Comment: Thanks for the very informative answer @MrkSef ! This gives me a better idea on how to approach this. I definitely check out `firstValueFrom` , like you said, these are probably enough for http requests.